# Problems with comments

Tags: support, comments

I posted an answer to this question.

[Linux: Run command on a batch of files, with matching output files](https://superuser.com/questions/660437/linux-run-command-on-a-batch-of-files-with-matching-output-files/660447#660447)

1. I am allowed to make comments to my post, but not to other peoples posts?
2. How do I put a linebreak in a comment?  When I press enter, the comment get submitted.

Linebreaks
End a line with two spaces to add a 
 linebreak:

https://superuser.com/editing-help#comment-formatting

I'm running Firefox 24 on Fedora 19 lxde.

Answer (score 7):

#### 1) You do not yet have the privilege to [comment everywhere](https://superuser.com/help/privileges/comment), which is earned at 50 rep.

At the moment I write this, you only have 41 reputation on Super User.

Until you reach that privilege, you can only comment on your own answers or within your own questions - though that normally does not take a very long wait.

#### 2) You don't put newlines in comments - they're single-line only.

If you have anything substantial enough to warrant multiple lines in a comment, you may be misusing comments. They exist primarily to request improvement or clarification in an answer, and they're transient - you should expect they could be deleted after a few days for clean-up purposes.

If you're writing information in comments that should probably be part of your answer, edit that information into your answer.

That said, if you really need to put something multiline in a comment, you could put it on [Pastebin](http://pastebin.com/) instead and link to it.

Comment: If only they were, in fact, cleaned up after a few days.

Comment: I read this as I can have multi-line comments.  http://superuser.com/editing-help#comment-formatting

Comment: @historystamp I see why you might think that - the code sample is multiline - but newlines are ignored in comments. If you somehow submit a comment with newlines in it, they'll be stripped out.